# Is it possible to use VisualStudio.com with VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to connect to TFS hosted at visualstudio.com via Visual Studio 2010? Everything appears to point me to download and install VS2012. Is there a Windows client possibly? Please, I know I should just upgrade to VS2012, but until I do, can I use VS2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use with VS2010 but you need to install a small patch:

[Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server 2012 Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)

Update provides compatibility between all VS 2010 products that connect to Team Foundation Server 2012 or the Team Foundation Service Preview